# Reading a value from a propery in Session object to cshtml

Tags: c#, session, razor

I am trying to display welcome text on my webpage from a property in session object using below

`<h3>@HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"]</h3>` which gives me the object itself but I am wondering how I can read a property from the `Application` object

**May I know a good way to do it?**

Comment: You'll have to cast the session variable as the Application object, then you'll have access to all the properties on the Application object.

Comment: I tried this too `@{(ApplicationFilterDto)HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"]}` but I still dont have access to the properties

Comment: wrap with parenthesis: `((ApplicationFilterDto)HttpContext.Current.Session["Applica‌​tion"]).someproperty`

Answer (score 0):

As I am reading this question and thinking the story, I think all you need to use is [TempData](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/476967/what-is-viewdata-viewbag-and-tempdata-mvc-option), As long as you need it, use keep and peek on it, If you need at long as user use your site, just go with the session.

If you need to have some data at the application level, you can create a static class and use that class to hold your data until the app shutdown or restart.

Answer (score -1):

You could deserialize an object with Json.NET/Newtonsoft. You would need to reference this library in your project. You can download it directly from the [website](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/) or via [Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/)

This is a sample of the object's properties

```
    public class ApplicationModel
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string WelcomeMessage { get; set; }
    }
```

In your cshtml

```
    @{
    var appSessionData = @HttpContext.Current.Session["Application"]
    var applicationData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApplicationModel>(appSessionData);
    <h3>@applicationData.WelcomeMessage</h3>
    }
```

Regards,
Vibhav Ramcharan

Comment: your assumption is that he serialized the object to json before storing it in session. The OP makes no mention of that